# Looking for title of latin textbook - US high-school 1960's

Tags: classical-latin

I'm trying to figure out what textbook I had for Latin, in a US high-school around 1968. (Chicago suburbs if that helps). I think the first story was about a boy and a girl on a picnic, because I remember "picus nicus".

I've searched around, and looked through old scans, but haven't stumbled on it yet.

Any clues? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might be **Latin for Americans** by Berthold Louis Ullman and Norman E. Henry (and, depending on the edition, sometimes also Charles Henderson, Jr.), published by Macmillan. The book appears to have been around since [at least 1941](https://books.google.de/books/about/Latin_for_Americans.html?id=CHANAQAAIAAJ&redir_esc=y).

I suspect so because of the following Google Books snippet preview:

[image: Snippet Preview]

The publication that this snippet is from has a [strangely incomplete citation](https://www.google.de/books/edition/Bulletin/fpRBAQAAIAAJ?hl=de&gbpv=0) on Google Books, but appears to be a bulletin of a certain “Council for Basic Education” from the year 1974.

And this one from a journal called “Theoria” published by Natal University College (South Africa) in 1960:

[image: Snippet Preview]

Comment: Thank you!  I remember "cocam colam" now, too.  The title is cringe-worthy, and the reviewers didn't like it, but that must be what we had.  (In my searches, 'picus' generated lots of hits for Pediatric-ICU.)